# VSTO Outlook integration - Outlook shutdown event for synchronization

Tags: c#, .net, events, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm working on a VSTO Outlook 2007 add-in that basically synchronizes Outlook data with web service. There are three types of synchronization that I want to have in the app: startup sync, manual sync and sync on shutdown. The first two as simple and are already done.

However I have problems finding an appropriate event to fire to handle my sync on shutdown. I tried hooking to the following two events but it seems that they are fired too late when add-in doesn't have access to Outlook data and this just doesn't work:

- `((Outlook.ApplicationEvents_Event)Application).Quit` (this one fires first, but it's already too late to access Outlook data collections and update them)
- `ThisAddIn.Shutdown` (this one fires after `Quit` so it's not good as well)

Are there any other events that are fired before those ones on Outlook shutdown that I could use? Or maybe someone knows any other way to handle sync-on-shutdown in Outlook add-in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explorer.Close() and Inspector.Close() fire before Application.Quit() - in them you can check:

- In Explorer.Close(): Application.Explorers.Count<=1 and Application.Inspectors.Count==0
- In Inspector.Close(): Application.Explorers.Count==0 and Application.Inspectors.Count<=1

If so, Outlook will close and you can fire your events. Just keep in mind that Outlook can be started window-less too (automation etc.) if thats an issue for you.