# outlook 2010 closeevent

Tags: c#, .net, events, vsto, outlook-addin

How to attach a handler when the user is closing outlook?

private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e) basicly doesn't work.

in here:
[VSTO Outlook integration - Outlook shutdown event for synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438086/vsto-outlook-integration-outlook-shutdown-event-for-synchronization)

I've found a suggestion to hook up to Explorer.Close() and Inspector.Close().

In here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsto/thread/7e3c3a98-2b01-4def-a83c-f560e4672e73

Helmut is attaching a handler like this:

```
_Inspector = inspector as Outlook.InspectorClass;

// register for the close event - used to release ourself from memory - intercept the close event

_Inspector.InspectorEvents_Event_Close += new Outlook.InspectorEvents_CloseEventHandler(_Inspector_InspectorEvents_Event_Close);
```

but there is no way I could repeat it on my machine (maybe it's my newer outlook...)

Anyone could help?

Answer (score -1):

You Must Inject file Into OUTLOOK.EXE process and in this dll you must Do Handle for WM_CLOSE message in WndProc. Try This Link : [How to Handle WNDPROC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624367/how-to-handle-wndproc-messages-in-wpf.). And this link explain you everything but this is about GETMINMAXINFO message you have WM_CLOSE : [All About Injecting int WNDPROC](http://nirvdrum.com/2010/03/25/how-to-take-full-page-or-full-canvas-screenshots-in-windows.html)